# How to remove the timezone offset from an NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get just `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` from an NSDateFormatter.

But the string spits out `Historical Date: 2016-08-23 14:03:00 +0000`

I do not want the seconds or the +0000.

What am I doing wrong?

```
int seconds = -( days * (24 * 60 * 60)); //24 hours, times 60 minutes, times 60 seconds
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSString* stringFromDate = [format stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate * pastDate = [[format dateFromString:stringFromDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds];

NSLog(@"Date: %@", pastDate);
```

Comment: Because NSDate will get the +0000, it's the NSString that won't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you printing `NSDate` object.
`NSDate` object encapsulates a single point in time, it is not responsible for it's string representation. 
What you really need to do, is to calculate exact date you need, and then format it into `NSString`.

Something like that:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *pastDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds];

NSString *yourDateInString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:pastDate];
NSLog(@"%@", yourDateInString);
```

Also, it is good practice to use `NSCalendar` and `NSCalendarComponents` to manipulate with dates and calculate new dates instead of just adding time interval.

Comment: Perfect! Next time I'll remember to calculate the time before formatting it. Care for a quick example? Is it backwards compatible with iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your coding first

```
 int seconds = -( 24 * (24 * 60 * 60)); //24 hours, times 60 minutes, times 60 seconds
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSString* stringFromDate = [format stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate * pastDate = [[format dateFromString:stringFromDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds];
NSLog(@"The pastDate is - %@",pastDate);
```

The printed result is

```
The pastDate is - 2016-07-31 14:30:00 +0000
```

> NSDate gets +0000

Then I tried with string

```
NSString *stringDate = [format stringFromDate:pastDate];
NSLog(@"The Date is: %@", stringDate);
```

Now the printed result is

```
The Date is: 2016-07-31 20:00
```

> String does not have +0000